# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Colspan issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I am trying to group 3 of my fields into the one row using the `col-sm-4` class, however I am having issues with how the row is being displayed. It is appearing off-center and not within the column as seen below.

[image]

The code for my form is the below:

```
<div class="hb-comment__form">
<h3 class="h3-header">Make a Booking</h3>
<div class="row">
    [response]
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        [text* your-name class:input__field class:size-2 placeholder "Your Name"]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        [email* your-email class:input__field class:type-2 class:size-2
        placeholder "Your Email"]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        [tel* telephone_number class:input__field class:type-2 class:size-2
        placeholder "Your Phone Number"]
    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="contactFormPickers">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label>
                            Arrival Date :[date* Arrival_Date class:input__field class:type-2
                            class:size-2]
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label>
                            Depart Date: [date* Depart_Date class:input__field class:type-2
                            class:size-2]
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label >
                            Guests: <br />
                            [select* no_of_guests class:input__field class:type-2 class:size-2 class:guest-picker include_blank "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10"]
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
[textarea* your-message class:input__field class:type-2 class:size-2
placeholder x5 "Your Message"] [recaptcha] [submit class:btn class:mb-0
class:btn--normal class:btn--md "Submit Booking"]
```

And the custom css class "contactFormPickers" is the below:

```
.contactFormPickers{
text-align:center;
margin: auto 0;
```

}

Any help fixing the above issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this apparently is a bootstrap issue. You are wrapping these three elements *twice*  into `.row` elements (which add certain margin and padding settings) - You should erase at least one of these `.row` layers.

Also, you might consider to erase the `.contactFormPickers` layer if you don't really need it.